# Remove an event field and reference it in Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

Using Logstash, I want to index documents into Elasticsearch and specify the type, id etc of the document that needs to be indexed. How can I specify those in my config without keeping useless fields in my documents?

Example: I want to specify the id used for insertion:

```
input {
    stdin {
        codec => json {}
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch { document_id => "%{[id]}" }
}
```

This will insert the document in Elasticsearch with the id *id* but the document will keep a redundant field "id" in the mapping. How can I avoid that?

I thought of adding

```
filter{ mutate { remove_field => "%{[id]}"} }
```

in the config, but the field is removed and cannot consequently be used as *document_id*...

Comment: Can someone explain why I got a -1 on the question, so I can improve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now this isn't possible. Logstash 1.5 introduces a @metadata field whose contents aren't included in what's eventually sent to the outputs, so you'd be able to create a [@metadata][id] field and refer to that in your output,

```
output {
    elasticsearch { document_id => "%{[@metadata][id]}" }
}
```

without that field polluting the message payload indexed to Elasticsearch. See the [@metadata documentation](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/master/docs/asciidoc/static/configuration.asciidoc#the-metadata-field).